# Ruby attr_writer methods in singleton classes

Tags: ruby

I can get a method that sets an instance variable in a singleton class to work if it does not end with `=`:

```
class Aaa
  class << self
    def config(&block)
      instance_eval(&block)
    end

    def set_blah(blah)
      @blah = blah
    end

    def blah
      @blah
    end
  end
end

Aaa.config {set_blah("something")}
Aaa.blah # => "something" as expected
```

When the method that sets the instance variable ends with a `=`, it doesn't work anymore:

```
class Bbb
  class << self
    def config(&block)
      instance_eval(&block)
    end

    def blah=(blah)
      @blah = blah
    end

    def blah
      @blah
    end
  end
end

Bbb.config {blah=("something")}
Bbb.blah # => nil, not sure why

# This works
Bbb.blah=("hi")
Bbb.blah # => "hi"
```

Why are the `set_blah` and `blah=` methods working differently?

Comment: Have you tried to use Struct class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calling `blah=` will create a local variable named `blah` and assign it the value of `("something")`, which is `"something"`. You have to add explicit receiver e.g.:

```
self.blah=("something")
```